# Time series analysis: Why am I getting a reciprocal condition number when trying to estimate VAR-Model? /w reproducible example

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, matrix

I'm currently trying to identify an appropriate VARMA(*p*, *q*)-representation for a multivariate time series using the `MTS::`-package in R. The series comprises *n* = 126 observations representing 12-hour intervals each and *k* = 14 dimensions. The goal is to identify relations among the series. Specifically, I'm interested in finding out whether the first time series is influenced by the other 13 in a unidirectional relationship.

Prior to the analysis, all series were tested for stationarity using the Augmented Dickey-Fuller- (ADF) and the Kwiatkowski-Phillips-Schmidt-Shin-Test (KPSS). In one case—namely, the suspected output time series of the MTS—ADF- und KPSS-test both suggested that the series was nonstationary, *DF* = -2.9581, *p* = 0.1784; *KPSS*-level = 0.7663, *p* < .01. However, as the graphical inspection didn't suggest a trend (see Fig. 1), I refrained from differencing the series:
[image: Fig. 1: Output time series]
For four other series the KPSS-Test suggested nonstationarity, albeit only barely (only just below *p* = .05). Since the time series plots didn't show any trends and the ADF-test indicated stationarity, I didn't difference these four series, either.

Following Tsay's ([2013](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Multivariate+Time+Series+Analysis%3A+With+R+and+Financial+Applications-p-9781118617908)) procedure, the first step then is selecting a sensible *p*-order, using

```
VARorder(da)
```

which should yield something like

```
selected order: aic =  5 
selected order: bic =  2 
selected order: hq =  2
```

indicating the appropriate *p* order by consulting various information criteria. However, for my data, the command gives

```
Error in solve.default(xpx, xpy) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.92466e-18
```

suggesting that the matrix containing my data is non-invertibile. Unfortunately, I can't quite figure out why. Possible problems I've ticked off the list:

- *m* < *k*: Observations by far outnumber dimensions
- Multicollinearity: I've checked the data by looking for high, significant correlations of individual series—there weren't any. Nevertheless, I tried excluding some series with the highest significant correlations (max *r* .85, min *r* = .56 or so). I still received the same error message (obviously with a different condition number).
- Nonstationarity: I've tried excluding the five series mentioned above. I still received the same error message (obviously with a different condition number).

**I'd be very grateful if you would share possible explanations and solutions for this error message**.

Note: I'm able to check different VAR models and their information criteria "by hand" using, for example

```
VAR <- VAR(da,
        2, #p order
        output = T)
```

But I'm not sure why `VARorder(da)` wouldn't suggest the appropriate VAR order itself.

---

### Reproducible Example

```
library(MTS)
library(tseries)
```

Part of the dataset:

```
data <- structure(c(16, 31, 22, 34, 6, 89, 40, 171, 15, 17, 36, 2445, 
1998, 3633, 2413, 4595, 3928, 19897, 21616, 32786, 24915, 33185, 
17234, 30094, 21407, 23071, 11214, 12381, 3504, 26791, 15769, 
16420, 6782, 12417, 7355, 6491, 3617, 3553, 1667, 3613, 2584, 
4256, 2329, 3993, 2033, 2234, 1573, 6873, 3229, 6535, 6087, 3137, 
1641, 1554, 2550, 8849, 3142, 3058, 1285, 2012, 1698, 2634, 1662, 
3193, 2917, 2936, 1484, 1417, 0.875, 7.51612903225806, 0.954545454545455, 
1.61764705882353, 0, 0.134831460674157, 7, 0.461988304093567, 
0.666666666666667, 4.64705882352941, 1.36111111111111, 13.1460122699386, 
8.7967967967968, 7.87723644371043, 4.394944053046, 11.9275299238302, 
10.1517311608961, 9.87390058802835, 7.97141006661732, 4.66802903678399, 
6.98539032711218, 3.49477173421727, 3.26819078565626, 6.65528012228351, 
5.59756154528892, 2.66598760348489, 2.12546816479401, 3.29036426782974, 
3.56449771689498, 5.98637602179836, 3.65660473080094, 3.5247868453106, 
1.4967561191389, 7.78650237577515, 2.5675050985724, 2.49622554305962, 
2.10201824716616, 2.08274697438784, 6.02279544091182, 8.03874896208137, 
3.05882352941176, 9.32894736842105, 4.8196650923143, 5.34510393188079, 
2.49335956714215, 2.26812891674127, 7.04704386522568, 5.14607885930452, 
10.0947661814803, 2.95791889824024, 3.70445211105635, 1.01817022633089, 
3.28153564899452, 2.38095238095238, 17.5701960784314, 5.12532489546841, 
2.08911521323997, 2.69882275997384, 8.70817120622568, 1.1317097415507, 
4.82508833922261, 4.56909643128322, 6.26594464500602, 5.98559348575008, 
10.5279396640384, 4.00340599455041, 1.06469002695418, 1.0317572335921, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0257668711656442, 0.03003003003003, 
0.0536746490503716, 0.0298383754662246, 0.0722524483133841, 0.17540733197556, 
0.0690556365281198, 0.0960862324204293, 0.049167327517843, 0.125426449929761, 
0.0515895736025313, 0.0599396541719856, 0.109058284043331, 0.040921194001962, 
0.0410038576567986, 0.0257713572320314, 0.0377998546159438, 0.113299086757991, 
0.268485685491396, 0.0468006848880715, 0.0713763702801462, 0.0328811560011796, 
0.109366191511637, 0.0626784500339905, 0.0514558619627176, 0.0470002764722145, 
0.0278637770897833, 0.296340731853629, 0.0916136174923886, 0.0487616099071207, 
0.101033834586466, 0.0553885787891799, 0.0290508389681943, 0.044761436301033, 
0.040734109221128, 0.191989828353465, 0.0216790339007711, 0.107463611025085, 
0.03672532517215, 0.0266140956136028, 0.0210392094357667, 0.0249847653869592, 
0.0193050193050193, 0.145098039215686, 0.0581986665159905, 0.026098026734564, 
0.0238718116415958, 0.119844357976654, 0.0248508946322068, 0.0318021201413428, 
0.0808656036446469, 0.0415162454873646, 0.053554650798622, 0.116900925608502, 
0.0286103542234332, 0.0235849056603774, 0.0289343683839097, 0.375, 
0.290322580645161, 0.772727272727273, 0.705882352941177, 0.166666666666667, 
0.865168539325843, 0.4, 0.649122807017544, 0.2, 0.235294117647059, 
0.583333333333333, 0.235173824130879, 0.212212212212212, 0.202587393338838, 
0.188976377952756, 0.305331882480958, 1.14052953156823, 0.371010705131427, 
0.390867875647668, 0.246294149942048, 0.459562512542645, 0.30700617748983, 
0.26824881049089, 0.56529540772247, 0.298920913719811, 0.24160201118287, 
0.173711432138398, 0.218318391083111, 0.308219178082192, 0.964540330708074, 
0.278711395776524, 0.253836784409257, 0.171040990858154, 0.349923491986792, 
0.36274643099932, 0.304729625635495, 0.287807575338678, 0.290458767238953, 
0.676064787042591, 0.389150290617216, 0.302631578947368, 0.437734962406015, 
0.369257191927866, 0.378412221387428, 0.288243974422036, 0.355416293643688, 
0.652256834075016, 0.186817983413357, 0.403840198203778, 0.166488140780413, 
0.120584852965336, 0.11954096270322, 0.196221815965874, 0.306306306306306, 
0.467843137254902, 0.269634987004181, 0.210693825588797, 0.320797907128842, 
0.366536964980545, 0.209244532803181, 0.222614840989399, 0.266135155656796, 
0.288808664259928, 0.400876918258691, 0.809050394240658, 0.256811989100817, 
0.207547169811321, 0.271700776287932, 0, 0.032258064516129, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 0.470588235294118, 0, 1.10265848670757, 
0.956456456456456, 0.891824938067713, 0.534189805221716, 1.06985854189336, 
0.820773930753564, 1.07574006131578, 0.739313471502591, 0.51610443481974, 
0.899859522376079, 0.482326352267591, 0.569571776720436, 0.897288496045723, 
0.59489886485729, 0.326600494126826, 0.332798287854468, 0.413294564251676, 
0.677511415525114, 0.924676197230413, 0.554569091254994, 0.685809987819732, 
0.285608964907107, 0.919626318756543, 0.376614547926581, 0.432444923740564, 
0.375172795134089, 0.312974950745849, 0.816436712657469, 0.725712704123997, 
0.504256965944272, 0.619595864661654, 0.478746243022757, 0.311795642374155, 
0.35120511559272, 0.282900626678603, 0.865225683407502, 0.200785683107813, 
0.738928460823784, 0.280642693190513, 0.444061113849187, 0.184252470513229, 
0.294942108470445, 0.307593307593308, 2.00666666666667, 0.361396767996384, 
0.233290897517505, 0.26651406147809, 1.39844357976654, 0.207256461232604, 
0.406949352179034, 0.706909643128322, 0.466305655836342, 0.382398997807704, 
0.63489886870072, 0.407356948228883, 0.1455525606469, 0.167254763585039, 
3.692549125, 4.49560512903226, 4.57798145454545, 4.55616644117647, 
4.1517775, 4.55915946067416, 4.414734775, 4.45239862573099, 4.59923626666667, 
4.27351670588235, 4.56756277777778, 4.71332677382413, 4.71433729079079, 
4.64946469199009, 4.54387499336925, 4.61450829858542, 4.59745392464358, 
4.59062127747902, 4.5796545548205, 4.57056009741963, 4.60275895199679, 
4.58094156061474, 4.5789076581757, 4.56992570233269, 4.60453077437287, 
4.56723077811972, 4.54220562867844, 4.50252512543413, 4.53417076712329, 
4.642812271957, 4.73391965692181, 4.72565443093788, 4.7228684402831, 
4.50389804397197, 4.54373440829368, 4.53955953104298, 4.59841393502903, 
4.57428621249648, 4.50534188722256, 4.48924115637974, 4.53550577592879, 
4.5775985881109, 4.59262387290683, 4.57157994039569, 4.54940686178062, 
4.44040071486124, 4.41989520343293, 4.37407497235559, 4.46162373737999, 
4.53045742004591, 4.51794264695252, 4.56885864743385, 4.65695446252285, 
4.56900272651223, 4.69658017058824, 4.64684664368855, 4.6081125436028, 
4.55441137606279, 4.51424117354086, 4.4736127445328, 4.36124198233215, 
4.58105553492787, 4.61192891095066, 4.50310046570623, 4.56664731882071, 
4.62616423876022, 4.58632562398922, 4.64963663726182, -1.00848575, 
0.208205709677419, 0.40566890909091, -0.0855384705882356, -0.690468166666666, 
-0.0295627640449432, 0.452610175, 0.0895930935672515, 0.611104066666667, 
0.417308529411764, 0.332088472222222, 0.180272839672802, 0.144860808808809, 
0.18300676355629, 0.143867004144218, 0.178214036343852, 0.177823023676171, 
0.042929696336131, 0.12914535311806, 0.0432498985542606, -0.0148116199478228, 
0.00884347455175494, 0.0122365454334457, 0.0409621980128927, 
-0.0268244293922546, -0.0193391807030476, -0.014688533618691, 
0.0364393041757536, 0.0657794837328769, -0.0669034146168492, 
-0.171487443908935, -0.147008289646772, -0.105609745502802, 0.115533307481678, 
0.0883407481985046, 0.0541025962101367, 0.0282320279236936, 0.021408362510555, 
0.111803380323935, 0.120495728757265, 0.118923532894737, 0.104660343515037, 
0.0249113044224991, -0.00539979163536142, 0.0483729503197248, 
0.172124465980304, 0.104896627463446, 0.00560021533537025, -0.00469096562403237, 
-0.0531827845447586, -0.224251195991457, -0.209440411858464, 
-0.199350975015235, -0.0750004839124836, -0.143215637647059, 
-0.0976614662673745, -0.128307466263526, -0.0236859610856772, 
-0.0395563929961087, 0.0233648389662022, 0.0843769752650179, 
-0.164816440394837, -0.14753778700361, 0.0325523658001883, -0.0288119273225913, 
-0.0765420718664851, -0.084179234501347, -0.0582728390966833, 
0.075183496875, 0.02426648, 0.0271562068181818, 0.0788219729411765, 
0.08238945, 0.0493402817977528, 0.02872707775, 0.0342396149122807, 
0.0252389386666667, 0.0183044394117647, 0.0393951455555556, 0.030129525795501, 
0.031027024024024, 0.0281381137186898, 0.0241995772855367, 0.0443059382350381, 
0.0427790892769857, 0.0707798925139468, 0.0456996758188379, 0.0356332810955896, 
0.0348289032907887, 0.0347024365357842, 0.0775101291841708, 0.0618462749378614, 
0.055448913391414, 0.0476508723913138, 0.0427640608810416, 0.0349019315475325, 
0.0376608332363014, 0.0291473890735695, 0.0512273642596233, 0.0554060555602923, 
0.055020037124742, 0.0705133741346541, 0.0703270357457512, 0.0602180559805885, 
0.0638396116726569, 0.0686834419307627, 0.0542862803719256, 0.0673001500608912, 
0.0537757401122291, 0.0752385264990602, 0.0493120754916273, 0.0511102803706486, 
0.0592842965174619, 0.0449520656893465, 0.0349389627717737, 0.0245876523890586, 
0.0282025061536079, 0.0274653890833971, 0.0221556541366847, 0.0258762808798215, 
0.0308798240219378, 0.0336267406756757, 0.0270719821529412, 0.0252643822657927, 
0.0340072633895608, 0.0398756244833224, 0.0403201777976654, 0.0389208850099404, 
0.0372876319081272, 0.0286002141609719, 0.0268911842719615, 0.0352231508236768, 
0.0511936396057593, 0.0673998798501362, 0.0567748048382749, 0.0426980801693719, 
0.06414205125, 0.04463416, 0.0550190559090909, 0.0298948785294118, 
0.05027976, 0.0365610662921348, 0.03549765, 0.0333254028070175, 
0.07370167, 0.0243866182352941, 0.0536612944444444, 0.112481859713701, 
0.123740007507508, 0.0846842881915772, 0.0415914044757563, 0.0360107505984766, 
0.0406890911405295, 0.0543990335226416, 0.0540293359085862, 0.0459330814982005, 
0.0393132071442906, 0.0735764532168148, 0.0780974799814321, 0.0485794028710042, 
0.0398182972859345, 0.0464864201811798, 0.0442254780631354, 0.0465678176237784, 
0.0462228359018265, 0.0402633947967601, 0.0312809160377957, 0.024281893361754, 
0.0286438232084931, 0.024409238141258, 0.0263882141400408, 0.0358999656447389, 
0.0359386544097318, 0.0363270329299184, 0.0522405332933413, 0.027402047882646, 
0.0303162957430341, 0.0249941684680451, 0.0309246510948905, 0.0325724327573253, 
0.0327702440727988, 0.0296018723813787, 0.0289401659249841, 0.0203381917648771, 
0.0223758755651905, 0.0273244281560826, 0.0175566904879251, 0.0197074362766975, 
0.023432296770262, 0.0277482831402831, 0.0962341700392157, 0.179647012091762, 
0.102838481222152, 0.0773100784826684, 0.0614378007782101, 0.038979027833002, 
0.0237781530035336, 0.0275677927107061, 0.0277110069795427, 0.0353478600062637, 
0.0336300274597189, 0.0324442857629428, 0.0314246574123989, 0.0308544836273818, 
0.0163602775, 0.0231132061290323, 0.0231632545454545, 0.0209158452941176, 
0.0387528266666667, 0.0271994058426966, 0.026902825, 0.0222509414035088, 
0.058897306, 0.0515867205882353, 0.0292888455555556, 0.0403766574233129, 
0.0332412379379379, 0.0326054351775392, 0.221786904682967, 0.0810602167573449, 
0.0491059532841141, 0.0680172347590089, 0.0326915253978534, 0.0276991810528884, 
0.0259867248645394, 0.0343522130480639, 0.0450440430544273, 0.0444782039609224, 
0.0548065791563507, 0.0602607108491179, 0.047723790529695, 0.044412910023423, 
0.035501276826484, 0.0544822339591654, 0.0325835376371362, 0.0324849677222899, 
0.0318033198171631, 0.0348969372634292, 0.0301580518014956, 0.0280368655060853, 
0.0270268415814211, 0.0329757841260906, 0.0939633692861428, 0.108691668973153, 
0.0663763363003096, 0.0421894485432331, 0.042267560455131, 0.0346524795892812, 
0.0314846770782095, 0.0307478555953447, 0.029016169294342, 0.0207958531936563, 
0.0244789454629916, 0.0300657588370314, 0.12321875505175, 0.156969885240676, 
0.0928580414381475, 0.0654918211068211, 0.0233775134901961, 0.0190742917843824, 
0.0303174138446849, 0.0542971883584042, 0.103453411673152, 0.0408653175944334, 
0.0348298761484099, 0.0251192069096431, 0.0224042062575211, 0.0245101381146257, 
0.0287224790881042, 0.038207901226158, 0.0449259481132075, 0.0401095539872971, 
0.06431219625, 0.0652975909677419, 0.0524747768181818, 0.062799505, 
0.030162605, 0.0569843502247191, 0.0426284115, 0.0539778900584795, 
0.0425711646666667, 0.0257402694117647, 0.0768474297222222, 0.0464627524458078, 
0.0536034053753754, 0.0729696639581613, 0.0450630715789474, 0.0411364451468988, 
0.0847578060667006, 0.120990120724732, 0.185452643092617, 0.0843113281269444, 
0.068734945615894, 0.0586641108781076, 0.0519009574399443, 0.0410267597241975, 
0.0358424622249731, 0.0423730277469551, 0.0397486685848047, 0.0372411033648332, 
0.0420564932077626, 0.0338923675603748, 0.0282253626209652, 0.0268264986455542, 
0.0310530747803008, 0.0337104439816381, 0.043912192507138, 0.0456373899445386, 
0.0421923110395355, 0.0444409041176471, 0.0429336742171566, 0.0588641466592859, 
0.0655345405534056, 0.0431616570911654, 0.0445072172348648, 0.0374211347332832, 
0.0462993288834235, 0.0423813194494181, 0.239949278226319, 0.190577284834861, 
0.1841104642428, 0.0978751339433818, 0.0451381913224906, 0.0460525053618107, 
0.0368871042047532, 0.0432519065250965, 0.0314233765372549, 0.0302869826488869, 
0.0396983423297263, 0.0369772504643558, 0.0382621084357977, 0.040080427917495, 
0.0475608491460542, 0.0578263571412301, 0.0642403059566787, 0.0682211473692452, 
0.0509836842338019, 0.0424014640769755, 0.037344879925876, 0.0369145077205363, 
0.039131866875, 0.0238462664516129, 0.0209872036363636, 0.0259887638235294, 
0.0204442366666667, 0.030026912247191, 0.0209505375, 0.0337630015204678, 
0.0298145266666667, 0.0252420076470588, 0.0249937972222222, 0.0241422896850716, 
0.022726420970971, 0.0499888298926507, 0.0325691627020307, 0.0292929473340588, 
0.0267112772403259, 0.0246896783434689, 0.0227751769059956, 0.046425635332154, 
0.0510110744531407, 0.0444560439957812, 0.0583711378089822, 0.0741870801488669, 
0.0726362979399262, 0.0679937124528629, 0.0777878008739076, 0.0545275898554236, 
0.0516303139269406, 0.033688001194431, 0.0255253517027078, 0.0224014677222899, 
0.0257852326747272, 0.0278081968269308, 0.0411679917063222, 0.0399426669234324, 
0.0450783619021288, 0.062533382212215, 0.0766013107378524, 0.0392909634652643, 
0.0677520030959752, 0.0487358949718045, 0.0409500609703735, 0.0484831394941147, 
0.0575566432365962, 0.0467859588182632, 0.041197086013986, 0.0227489903972065, 
0.0231279932796531, 0.0196208806426932, 0.0160949820929851, 0.0216375935607268, 
0.0246020068251066, 0.033239185971686, 0.0231248863137255, 0.0172195677477681, 
0.0204789047422024, 0.0373765438194899, 0.0336685210894942, 0.0286320009940358, 
0.0222365505300353, 0.0203177463933181, 0.0207522869434416, 0.0253700886313811, 
0.0302044114158382, 0.054381401907357, 0.0713482826145553, 0.0612009131968949, 
0.01997317625, 0.0510981161290323, 0.0535885127272727, 0.0252178452941176, 
0.0224598566666667, 0.0366746406741573, 0.03129685, 0.0314023360233918, 
0.0331178286666667, 0.0204349776470588, 0.0457561375, 0.0965838858568507, 
0.0903712287287287, 0.0623022909441233, 0.0528139293410692, 0.0554109867247008, 
0.0436485353869654, 0.0460532286274313, 0.0348924079848261, 0.0353313444763009, 
0.0310355385912101, 0.0307351182763297, 0.0292634714517814, 0.0731096677078487, 
0.0454055047414397, 0.0384545797754757, 0.0389100532370251, 0.0528891220418383, 
0.0338050350171233, 0.0533953797917211, 0.0647036425898916, 0.0532260353227771, 
0.0568478851371277, 0.0296690730450189, 0.0285812043507818, 0.030679913572639, 
0.0334435134089024, 0.0384176397410639, 0.0355680524295141, 0.0277129941876557, 
0.0273872154411765, 0.0841495991541353, 0.0663000777157578, 0.0435628795391936, 
0.0429536104771274, 0.0463072918531782, 0.0305447542911634, 0.021211754837771, 
0.021843973428306, 0.0222774719204285, 0.0177299032364055, 0.0213700710870258, 
0.0283763050578915, 0.0321798532818533, 0.0345026179607843, 0.0326594259238332, 
0.0430079570337365, 0.0410183927403532, 0.0343477150194553, 0.028561967693837, 
0.0349459587161366, 0.0315691636294609, 0.0787937060168472, 0.0552217647979956, 
0.101648102811107, 0.0634827074250681, 0.0437294484501348, 0.0412089564573042, 
0.020856236875, 0.0562083170967742, 0.0308131295454545, 0.0396829629411765, 
0.100044611666667, 0.0456313075280899, 0.04957125, 0.0409887112865497, 
0.0194665993333333, 0.326012851764706, 0.0764910805555556, 0.0588664084867076, 
0.0661107557557558, 0.0637056179466006, 0.0426115840033154, 0.0408393569096844, 
0.039273578385947, 0.0537249937176459, 0.0547690406180607, 0.0606379183187946, 
0.0514832675095324, 0.0479212357993069, 0.0421727962167808, 0.0411807343656543, 
0.0398579445975615, 0.0358253226994929, 0.039641051007669, 0.0322878620466844, 
0.0396163507420091, 0.0345283438468142, 0.0352380429323356, 0.034724115225335, 
0.0309002053966382, 0.0284429056938069, 0.0274001185588035, 0.0347561315667848, 
0.0324393124136024, 0.0407634359696032, 0.0359587619076185, 0.0309502446720177, 
0.0330951520897833, 0.0297507953477444, 0.0458972592099614, 0.0486794437766091, 
0.045119072110182, 0.0354557688898836, 0.0276929989828353, 0.0236847299578059, 
0.0239514215856302, 0.0323983291507269, 0.0246527813372762, 0.0316129636595473, 
0.0329225525289458, 0.0324244047619048, 0.0365879505882353, 0.0652355384789242, 
0.0561048074474857, 0.0688581608894702, 0.0702260007782101, 0.0470446928429423, 
0.0310852744994111, 0.0419289434320425, 0.0312496483754513, 0.040507020357031, 
0.0374511567706548, 0.0364719567438692, 0.0343822626684636, 0.0322565266760762
), .Dim = c(68L, 14L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
```

Test for stationarity using:

```
adf.test(data[,1])
kpss.test(data[,1])
```

Identify appropriate VAR(p)-order:

```
VARorder(data)

Error in solve.default(xpx, xpy) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.106e-26
```

Answer (score 1):

You're underestimating the number of parameters required. In a $\text{VAR}(p)$ with $k$ series and no mean, there are $pk^2$ regression coefficients, $pk$ per variable. The function `MTS::VARorder` tests up to $p=13$, which for $k=14$ gives 2548 parameters, 182 per variable. This is already more than your 126 observations.

You need to reduce the largest $p$ that you'll consider (parameter `maxp`). When comparing AIC, it has to be done on the *same* data for all models, which is why you will lose not the first $p$ data points at each $p$, but the largest $p$ for all of them (`MTS::VARorder` does this automatically). So if that's 13, you effectively only have 113 observations. Take that into consideration when choosing an appropriate largest $p$ to check.